# How to join filesystem path strings in PHP?

Tags: php, string, file

Is there a builtin function in PHP to intelligently join path strings? The function, given `abc/de/` and `/fg/x.php` as arguments, should return `abc/de/fg/x.php`; the same result should be given using `abc/de` and `fg/x.php` as arguments for that function.

If not, is there an available class? It could also be valuable for splitting paths or removing parts of them. If you have written something, may you share your code here?

It is ok to always use `/`, I am coding for Linux only.

In Python there is `os.path.join`, which is great.

Comment: Note that your example is quite misleading since `os.path.join('some/relative/path, '/an/absolute/path')` will always return `/an/absolute/path`. So you're either looking for an `os.path.join` replacement (then fix your example) or something that is close to it, with the exception that absolute paths coming second (or nth) are treated as relative paths.

Comment: @Tibo, and the upvoters of his comment: no, the example is not misleading at all, except if one ignores the gist of the question and insists on overemphasizing the the Python reference, which is a marginal remark for orientation. The question is perfectly clear about what it wants, which is *not* exactly `os.path.join`. Read: "The function, given `abc/de/` and `/fg/x.php` as arguments, should return `abc/de/fg/x.php`".

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Since this seems to be a popular question and the comments are filling with "features suggestions" or "bug reports"... All this code snippet does is join two strings with a slash without duplicating slashes between them. That's all. No more, no less. It does not evaluate actual paths on the hard disk nor does it actually keep the beginning slash (add that back in if needed, at least you can be sure this code always returns a string *without* starting slash).

```
join('/', array(trim("abc/de/", '/'), trim("/fg/x.php", '/')));
```

The end result will always be a path with no slashes at the beginning or end and no double slashes within. Feel free to make a function out of that.

EDIT:
Here's a nice flexible function wrapper for above snippet. You can pass as many path snippets as you want, either as array or separate arguments:

```
function joinPaths() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $paths = array();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        $paths = array_merge($paths, (array)$arg);
    }

    $paths = array_map(create_function('$p', 'return trim($p, "/");'), $paths);
    $paths = array_filter($paths);
    return join('/', $paths);
}

echo joinPaths(array('my/path', 'is', '/an/array'));
//or
echo joinPaths('my/paths/', '/are/', 'a/r/g/u/m/e/n/t/s/');
```

:o)

Comment: function pj($a,$b) { return rtrim($a, '/') .'/'. ltrim($b, '/'); }

Comment: This doesn't always work as described.  joinPaths('', 'foo.jpg') becomes '/foo.jpg'.  I noticed this after my php file manager started writing user-uplaoded files to the root of the filesystem!  A corrected version should remove any paths that are empty strings.

Comment: @Joe I'd first question why your first argument is empty; but fair enough, updated to filter out empty segments.

Comment: You could probably shave off a few microseconds by calling `array_filter` before calling `array_map`. This way, empty elements won't be iterated.

Comment: Should this be using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of '/'?

Comment: As David Miller's answer below points out, this does not work with absolute paths. E.g. joinPaths("/my/absolute/", "path/") returns "my/absolute/path".

Comment: The function does not work properly `joinPath('/a', '/b')` should return  `'/b'`

Comment: Well, first that is how os.path.join works in python. And `/b` means what it means, `/` is the universal root. I think that this function should have a similar behaviour as the linux command `cd`. So `cd /a` and `cd /b` and you are in `/b`, but `cd /a` and `cd b` and you are in `/a/b`.

Comment: @fe_ That's a completely different function from what the question was asking about.

Comment: I do not agree as the person clearly notified that he used to results given by python's `os.path.join` which gives this result and which he finds great. So I do not believe that it is an other function. Just as `join('/a/b','../c')` should return `/a/c` without any external normalizing needed.

Comment: @fe_lix_ *"The function, given "abc/de/" and "/fg/x.php" as arguments, should return "abc/de/fg/x.php"; the same result should be given using "abc/de" and "fg/x.php" as arguments for that function."* – OP

Comment: Well in that case there is a confusion on that level in the question, as os.path.join would not return this.

Comment: @fe_lix_ Yup. And since `os.path.join` is only a footnote, this answer addresses the larger part of the question.

Answer (score 153):

```
function join_paths() {
    $paths = array();

    foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
        if ($arg !== '') { $paths[] = $arg; }
    }

    return preg_replace('#/+#','/',join('/', $paths));
}
```

My solution is simpler and more similar to the way Python os.path.join works

Consider these test cases

```
array               my version    @deceze      @david_miller    @mark

['','']             ''            ''           '/'              '/'
['','/']            '/'           ''           '/'              '/'
['/','a']           '/a'          'a'          '//a'            '/a'
['/','/a']          '/a'          'a'          '//a'            '//a'
['abc','def']       'abc/def'     'abc/def'    'abc/def'        'abc/def'
['abc','/def']      'abc/def'     'abc/def'    'abc/def'        'abc//def'
['/abc','def']      '/abc/def'    'abc/def'    '/abc/def'       '/abc/def'
['','foo.jpg']      'foo.jpg'     'foo.jpg'    '/foo.jpg'       '/foo.jpg'
['dir','0','a.jpg'] 'dir/0/a.jpg' 'dir/a.jpg'  'dir/0/a.jpg'    'dir/0/a.txt'
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it best matches the question -  it is the closest to `os.path.join` and does *intelligently join path strings*. The answer could be improved by adding the "reference" implementation of `os.path.join`, and indicating the OP's specific that break the rule (test case `['abc','/def']` is wrong w.r.t `os.path.join`, but right as per the question).

Comment: @qix why? Windows understands forward slashes just fine

Comment: @RiccardoGalli Because platform XYZ may use dots, for example. Linux and windows may not be the only platforms that support PHP. Why not be a good engineer and use the constant?

Comment: @qix look, I do understand your point, usually I'd agree with you, but realistically PHP isn't going to run on platforms that don't use slashes as path separator anytime soon, and to use the constant the preg_replace() would become a real mess (you'd need to escape the path separator in the regexp), so I choose this tradeoff.

Comment: So you're cutting corners because you're lazy, even though string interpolation of constants in PHP is nearly free? Tsk.

Comment: As a note, my team has just found a case where `/` separators don't work (an old PHP5.3.4 install on a Windows Server 2012 using the msys git shell).

Comment: FWIW, the argument between Qix and Riccardo can be easily solved by using this regular expression instead: `"#[\\\\/]+#"` this will convert all combinations of `\ `  and `/` to a single `/`. If you want to use another character, just change the second parameter to preg_replace() to whatever you want (due to the fact that we are using func_get_args(); how you do that exactly can be slightly little tricky but not worth spelling out; just use a global\private member).

Answer (score 18):

@deceze's function doesn't keep the leading / when trying to join a path that starts with a Unix absolute path, e.g. `joinPaths('/var/www', '/vhosts/site');`.

```
function unix_path() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $paths = array();

  foreach($args as $arg) {
    $paths = array_merge($paths, (array)$arg);
  }

  foreach($paths as &$path) {
    $path = trim($path, '/');
  }

  if (substr($args[0], 0, 1) == '/') {
    $paths[0] = '/' . $paths[0];
  }

  return join('/', $paths);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

My take:

```
function trimds($s) {
    return rtrim($s,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

function joinpaths() {
    return implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_map('trimds', func_get_args()));
}
```

I'd have used an anonymous function for `trimds`, but older versions of PHP don't support it.

Example:

```
join_paths('a','\\b','/c','d/','/e/','f.jpg'); // a\b\c\d\e\f.jpg (on Windows)
```

---

Updated <del>April 2013</del> <del>March 2014</del> **May 2018**:

```
function join_paths(...$paths) {
    return preg_replace('~[/\\\\]+~', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $paths));
}
```

This one will correct any slashes to match your OS, won't remove a leading slash, and clean up and multiple slashes in a row.

Comment: it always creates an absolute path, but at least somebody mentioned DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR...

Answer (score 7):

**If you know the file/directory exists**, you can add extra slashes (that may be unnecessary), then call [realpath](http://php.net/manual/function.realpath.php), i.e.

`realpath(join('/', $parts));`

This is of course not quite the same thing as the Python version, but in many cases may be good enough.

Answer (score 7):

As a fun project, I created yet another solution. Should be universal for all operating systems.

For PHP 7.4+:

```php
/**
 * Join string into a single URL string.
 *
 * @param string $parts,... The parts of the URL to join.
 * @return string The URL string.
 */
function join_paths(...$parts) {
    if (sizeof($parts) === 0) return '';
    $prefix = ($parts[0] === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '';
    $processed = array_filter(
        array_map(fn ($part) => rtrim($part, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR), $parts),
        fn ($part) => !empty($part)
    );
    return $prefix . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $processed);
}
```

For PHP 7.2+:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Join string into a single URL string.
 *
 * @param string $parts,... The parts of the URL to join.
 * @return string The URL string.
 */
function join_paths(...$parts) {
    if (sizeof($parts) === 0) return '';
    $prefix = ($parts[0] === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '';
    $processed = array_filter(array_map(function ($part) {
        return rtrim($part, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }, $parts), function ($part) {
        return !empty($part);
    });
    return $prefix . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $processed);
}
```

For PHP version before 7.2:

```php
/**
 * Join string into a single URL string.
 *
 * @param string $parts,... The parts of the URL to join.
 * @return string The URL string.
 */
function join_paths() {
    $parts = func_get_args();
    if (sizeof($parts) === 0) return '';
    $prefix = ($parts[0] === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '';
    $processed = array_filter(array_map(function ($part) {
        return rtrim($part, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }, $parts), function ($part) {
        return !empty($part);
    });
    return $prefix . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $processed);
}
```

Some test case for its behaviour.

```php
// relative paths
var_dump(join_paths('hello/', 'world'));
var_dump(join_paths('hello', 'world'));
var_dump(join_paths('hello', '', 'world'));
var_dump(join_paths('', 'hello/world'));
echo "\n";

// absolute paths
var_dump(join_paths('/hello/', 'world'));
var_dump(join_paths('/hello', 'world'));
var_dump(join_paths('/hello/', '', 'world'));
var_dump(join_paths('/hello', '', 'world'));
var_dump(join_paths('', '/hello/world'));
var_dump(join_paths('/', 'hello/world'));
```

Results:

```
string(11) "hello/world"
string(11) "hello/world"
string(11) "hello/world"
string(11) "hello/world"

string(12) "/hello/world"
string(12) "/hello/world"
string(12) "/hello/world"
string(12) "/hello/world"
string(12) "/hello/world"
string(12) "/hello/world"
```

**Update**: Added a version that supports PHP before 7.2.

**Update**: Added a version for PHP 7.4+ with [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php).

Comment: +1 Thanks alot @Koala Yeung. Your solution is compatible with PHP-versions above v7.2. The code from the accepted answer uses create_function() which is deprecated in versions above 7.2 - in 2013 we just had PHP v5.5 though.

Comment: Thanks Koala Yeung! This improves nicely upon the quite useful solution by @Riccardo Galli, which was my previous go-to for the task. I can't find a way to break this one, and it's portable as long as your PHP is reasonably current. I'm happy with that.

Comment: @JackLeEmmerdeur: Added a version that works with older PHP. But the PHP 7.2+ is, IMO, cleaner to read.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is using `implode()` and `explode()`.

```
$a = '/a/bc/def/';
$b = '/q/rs/tuv/path.xml';

$path = implode('/',array_filter(explode('/', $a . $b)));

echo $path;  // -> a/bc/def/q/rs/tuv/path.xml
```

Comment: Try url `/offset/0/limit/1`.

Answer (score 5):

Elegant Python-inspired PHP one-liner way to join path.

This code doesn't use unnecessary array.

#### Multi-platform

```
function os_path_join(...$parts) {
  return preg_replace('#'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'+#', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_filter($parts)));
}
```

#### Unix based systems

```
function os_path_join(...$parts) {
  return preg_replace('#/+#', '/', implode('/', array_filter($parts)));
}
```

#### Unix based system without REST parameters (don't respect explicit PEP8 philosophy) :

```
function os_path_join() {
  return preg_replace('#/+#', '/', implode('/', array_filter(func_get_args())));
}
```

### Usage

```
$path = os_path_join("", "/", "mydir/", "/here/");
```

#### Bonus : if you want really follow Python os.path.join(). First argument is required :

```
function os_path_join($path=null, ...$paths) {
  if (!is_null($path)) {
    throw new Exception("TypeError: join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'", 1);
  }
  $path = rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
  foreach ($paths as $key => $current_path) {
    $paths[$key] = $paths[$key] = trim($current_path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
  }
  return implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_merge([$path], array_filter($paths)));
}
```

Check os.path.join() source if you want : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ntpath.py

Warning : This solution is not suitable for urls.

Answer (score 3):

The solution below uses the logic proposed by @RiccardoGalli, but is improved to avail itself of the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant, as @Qix and @FélixSaparelli suggested, and, more important, to **trim each given element** to avoid space-only folder names appearing in the final path (it was a requirement in my case).

Regarding the escape of directory separator inside the `preg_replace()` pattern, as you can see I used the `preg_quote()` function which does the job fine.
Furthermore, I would replace *mutiple separators* only (RegExp quantifier `{2,}`).

```
// PHP 7.+
function paths_join(string ...$parts): string {
    $parts = array_map('trim', $parts);
    $path = [];

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if ($part !== '') {
            $path[] = $part;
        }
    }

    $path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);

    return preg_replace(
        '#' . preg_quote(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . '{2,}#',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        $path
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for getting parts of paths you can use pathinfo
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

for joining the response from @deceze looks fine

Answer (score 2):

A different way of attacking this one:

```
function joinPaths() {
  $paths = array_filter(func_get_args());
  return preg_replace('#/{2,}#', '/', implode('/', $paths));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a corrected version of the function posted by deceze.  Without this change, joinPaths('', 'foo.jpg') becomes '/foo.jpg'

```
function joinPaths() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $paths = array();
    foreach ($args as $arg)
        $paths = array_merge($paths, (array)$arg);

    $paths2 = array();
    foreach ($paths as $i=>$path)
    {   $path = trim($path, '/');
        if (strlen($path))
            $paths2[]= $path;
    }
    $result = join('/', $paths2); // If first element of old path was absolute, make this one absolute also
    if (strlen($paths[0]) && substr($paths[0], 0, 1) == '/')
        return '/'.$result;
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be work quite well, and looks reasonably neat to me.

```
private function JoinPaths() {
  $slash = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $sections = preg_split(
          "@[/\\\\]@",
          implode('/', func_get_args()),
          null,
          PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  return implode($slash, $sections);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution found:

```
function joinPaths($leftHandSide, $rightHandSide) { 
    return rtrim($leftHandSide, '/') .'/'. ltrim($rightHandSide, '/'); 
}
```

NOTE: Copied from the comment by user89021

Answer (score 1):

OS-independent version based on [the answer by mpen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641174/930640) but encapsulated into a single function and with the option to add a trailing path separator.

```
function joinPathParts($parts, $trailingSeparator = false){
    return implode(
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 
        array_map(
            function($s){
                return rtrim($s,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
            }, 
            $parts)
        )
        .($trailingSeparator ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '');
}
```

Or for you one-liner lovers:

```
function joinPathParts($parts, $trailingSeparator = false){
    return implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_map(function($s){return rtrim($s,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);}, $parts)).($trailingSeparator ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '');
}
```

Simply call it with an array of path parts:

```
// No trailing separator - ex. C:\www\logs\myscript.txt
$logFile = joinPathParts([getcwd(), 'logs', 'myscript.txt']);

// Trailing separator - ex. C:\www\download\images\user1234\
$dir = joinPathParts([getcwd(), 'download', 'images', 'user1234'], true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note OP is asking for something slightly different from https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join which does more than just join paths with the right number of separators.

While what they have asked for has been answered, for anyone skim reading the Q&A, there will be the following differences and ambiguous cases between what was asked for and `os.path.join()`:

Many of the above solutions don't work for the root only case `['/'] => '/'`

os.path.join drop all args to the left of the rightmost absolute path e.g.  `['a', 'b', '/c'] => '/c'` which to be fair is probably not the behaviour you want if you are refactoring existing php which has a lot of path segments appear like they are absolute paths.

Another difference with os.path.join is it won't drop additional separators within a single string `['a///', 'b', 'c'] => 'a///b/c'`

Another special case is one or more empty strings resulting in a trailing slash for os.path.join: `['a', ''] or ['a', '', ''] => 'a/'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that behaves like [Node's `path.resolve`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to):

```
function resolve_path() {
    $working_dir = getcwd();
    foreach(func_get_args() as $p) {
        if($p === null || $p === '') continue;
        elseif($p[0] === '/') $working_dir = $p;
        else $working_dir .= "/$p";
    }
    $working_dir = preg_replace('~/{2,}~','/', $working_dir);
    if($working_dir === '/') return '/';
    $out = [];
    foreach(explode('/',rtrim($working_dir,'/')) as $p) {
        if($p === '.') continue;
        if($p === '..') array_pop($out);
        else $out[] = $p;
    }
    return implode('/',$out);
}
```

Test cases:

```
resolve_path('/foo/bar','./baz')         # /foo/bar/baz
resolve_path('/foo/bar','/tmp/file/')    # /tmp/file
resolve_path('/foo/bar','/tmp','file')   # /tmp/file
resolve_path('/foo//bar/../baz')         # /foo/baz
resolve_path('/','foo')                  # /foo
resolve_path('/','foo','/')              # /
resolve_path('wwwroot', 'static_files/png/', '../gif/image.gif') 
                                  # __DIR__.'/wwwroot/static_files/gif/image.gif'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the great answer of Ricardo Galli, a bit of improvement to avoid killing the protocol prefix.

The idea is to test for the presence of a protocol in one argument, and maintain it into the result. WARNING: this is a naive implementation!

For example:

```
array("http://domain.de","/a","/b/")
```

results to (keeping protocol)

```
"http://domain.de/a/b/"
```

instead of (killing protocol)

```
"http:/domain.de/a/b/"
```

But http://codepad.org/hzpWmpzk needs a better code writing skill.

Answer (score 0):

I love [Riccardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575293/9714920) and I think it is the best answer.

I am using it to join paths in **url** building, but with one small change to handle protocols' double slash:

```
function joinPath () {
    $paths = array();

    foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
        if ($arg !== '') { $paths[] = $arg; }
    }

    // Replace the slash with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    $paths = preg_replace('#/+#', '/', join('/', $paths));
    return preg_replace('#:/#', '://', $paths);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function path_combine($paths) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($paths); ++$i) {
    $paths[$i] = trim($paths[$i]);
  }

  $dirty_paths = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $paths));
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($dirty_paths); ++$i) {
    $dirty_paths[$i] = trim($dirty_paths[$i]);
  }

  $unslashed_paths = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($dirty_paths); ++$i) {
    $path = $dirty_paths[$i];
    if (strlen($path) == 0) continue;
    array_push($unslashed_paths, $path);
  }

  $first_not_empty_index = 0;
  while(strlen($paths[$first_not_empty_index]) == 0) {
    ++$first_not_empty_index;
  }
  $starts_with_slash = $paths[$first_not_empty_index][0] == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  return $starts_with_slash
    ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $unslashed_paths)
    : join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $unslashed_paths);
}
```

Example usage:

```
$test = path_combine([' ', '/cosecheamo', 'pizze', '///// 4formaggi', 'GORGONZOLA']);
echo $test;
```

Will output:

```
/cosecheamo/pizze/4formaggi/GORGONZOLA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function joinPath(): string {

        $path = '';
        foreach (func_get_args() as $numArg => $arg) {

            $arg = trim($arg);

            $firstChar = substr($arg, 0, 1);
            $lastChar = substr($arg, -1);

            if ($numArg != 0 && $firstChar != '/') {
                $arg = '/'.$arg;
                }

            # Eliminamos el slash del final
            if ($lastChar == '/') {
                $arg = rtrim($arg, '/');
                }

            $path .= $arg;
            }

        return $path;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm most seem a bit over complicated. Dunno, this is my take on it:

```php
// Takes any amount of arguments, joins them, then replaces double slashes
function join_urls() {
   $parts = func_get_args();
   $url_part = implode("/", $parts);
   return preg_replace('/\/{1,}/', '/', $url_part);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who want a join function that does the Windows backslash and the Linux forward slash.

Usage:

```
<?php
use App\Util\Paths
echo Paths::join('a','b'); //Prints 'a/b' on *nix, or 'a\\b' on Windows
```

Class file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Util;

class Paths
{
  public static function join_with_separator($separator, $paths) {
    $slash_delimited_path = preg_replace('#\\\\#','/', join('/', $paths));
    $duplicates_cleaned_path = preg_replace('#/+#', $separator, $slash_delimited_path);
    return $duplicates_cleaned_path;
  }

  public static function join() {
    $paths = array();

    foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
      if ($arg !== '') { $paths[] = $arg; }
    }
    return Paths::join_with_separator(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $paths);
  }
}
```

Here's the test function:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Util\Paths;

class PathsTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testWindowsPaths()
  {
    $TEST_INPUTS = [
      [],
      ['a'],
      ['a','b'],
      ['C:\\','blah.txt'],
      ['C:\\subdir','blah.txt'],
      ['C:\\subdir\\','blah.txt'],
      ['C:\\subdir','nested','1/2','blah.txt'],
    ];
    $EXPECTED_OUTPUTS = [
      '',
      'a',
      'a\\b',
      'C:\\blah.txt',
      'C:\\subdir\\blah.txt',
      'C:\\subdir\\blah.txt',
      'C:\\subdir\\nested\\1\\2\\blah.txt',
    ];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($TEST_INPUTS); $i++) {
      $actualPath = Paths::join_with_separator('\\', $TEST_INPUTS[$i]);
      $expectedPath = $EXPECTED_OUTPUTS[$i];
      $this->assertEquals($expectedPath, $actualPath);
    }
  }
  public function testNixPaths()
  {
    $TEST_INPUTS = [
      [],
      ['a'],
      ['a','b'],
      ['/home','blah.txt'],
      ['/home/username','blah.txt'],
      ['/home/username/','blah.txt'],
      ['/home/subdir','nested','1\\2','blah.txt'],
    ];
    $EXPECTED_OUTPUTS = [
      '',
      'a',
      'a/b',
      '/home/blah.txt',
      '/home/username/blah.txt',
      '/home/username/blah.txt',
      '/home/subdir/nested/1/2/blah.txt',
    ];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($TEST_INPUTS); $i++) {
      $actualPath = Paths::join_with_separator('/', $TEST_INPUTS[$i]);
      $expectedPath = $EXPECTED_OUTPUTS[$i];
      $this->assertEquals($expectedPath, $actualPath);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = [sys_get_temp_dir(), "path1","path2", "filename.pdf"];
$filename = implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $args);
// output "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\path1\path2\filename.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one gives the same output as [Riccardo Galli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575293/3271687), with the following improvements:

- Accept nested arrays of subpaths, recursively;
- Accept null values correctly.

```
function joinPaths(string|array|null ...$paths): string
{
    $flatPaths = [];
    array_walk_recursive($paths, function ($p) use (&$flatPaths) { $flatPaths[] = $p; });
    $paths = array_filter($flatPaths, fn ($p) => '' !== $p && null !== $p);

    return preg_replace('+/{2,}+', '/', implode('/', $paths));
}
```

```
----------------- Similar behaviours ----------------

Array                  My version     @RiccardoGalli

['','']                ''             ''
['','/']               '/'            '/'
['/','a']              '/a'           '/a'
['/','/a']             '/a'           '/a'
['abc','def']          'abc/def'      'abc/def'
['abc','/def']         'abc/def'      'abc/def'
['/abc','def']         '/abc/def'     '/abc/def'
['','foo.jpg']         'foo.jpg'      'foo.jpg'
['dir','0','a.jpg']    'dir/0/a.jpg'  'dir/0/a.jpg'

----------------- Improvements ----------------------

Array                  My version     @RiccardoGalli

[null,'foo.jpg']       'foo.jpg'      '/foo.jpg'
['dir',['0','a.jpg']]  'dir/0/a.jpg'  ERROR
[[], []]               ''             ERROR
[[['a']],[],null,'b']  'a/b'          ERROR
```

Answer (score -9):

I liked several solutions presented. But those who does replacing all '/+' into '/' (regular expressions) are forgetting that os.path.join() from python can handle this kind of join:

```
os.path.join('http://example.com/parent/path', 'subdir/file.html')
```

Result: 'http://example.com/parent/path/subdir/file.html'

Comment: Question asked for PHP, answer is for Python