# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '{filename}'

Tags: php, wordpress

While loading my blog, I see the following wrrors on the console and white screen as a result:

> Warning:
> require(/home/u8070024/public_html/wp-content/themes//css/critical_css.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/u8070024/public_html/wp-content/themes/azurelo/functions.php on
> line 49
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/home/u8070024/public_html/wp-content/themes//css/critical_css.php'
> (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in
> /home/u8070024/public_html/wp-content/themes/azurelo/functions.php on
> line 49

So I can't acces my blog...
how to solve this problem?.
please somebody help me:(

[[image]

Comment: The double "//" (after `themes`) in the critical_css.php file path doesn't look right... by chance are you concatinating a path and including too many "/" characters?

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Please describe your problem better or your question will be closed and/or downvoated. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you add the code on line 49 of /home/u8070024/public_html/wp-content/themes/azurelo/functions.php to your question... it should reveal where the error is. Ideally show any previous lines that may be applicable too.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mTXz.jpg

Comment: You might also take into consideration the path wil multiple `/` so here's the best anser it might suit you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575293/3735825

Answer (score 0):

As @scunlife mentioned, you have `//` where you should have `/` and to avoid these kind of issues, you might use this function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575293/3735825

And replace the reuired with the joined path from the function mentioned above.